# tolower() is not working for Ü,Ö in c++

Tags: c++, tolower

When I tried tolower() with non english charecters in c++ it's not working normally. I searched that issue and I came across something about locale but I am not sure about best solution of that.

My sample code is below:

```
printf("%c ",tolower('Ü'));
```

Comment: Mentioned in Bart van Ingen Schenau's answer, but worth highlighting: *characters cannot generally be assumed to have lower/upper case variants*. Read up on [letter case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case).

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the standard C++ library does not have sufficient support for changing the case of all possible non-English characters (in so far as those characters that have case variants at all). This limitation is caused by the fact that the C++ standard assumes that a single character and its case variants occupy exactly one `char` object (or `wchar_t` object for wide characters) and for non-English characters that is not guaranteed to be true (also depending on how the characters are coded).

If your environment uses a single-byte encoding for the relevant characters, this might give you what you want:

```
std::cout << std::tolower('Ü', locale());
```

With wide characters, you will probably have more luck:

```
std::wcout << std::tolower(L'Ü', locale());
```

but even that won't give the correct result for `toupper(L'ß')`, which would be the two-character sequence `L"SS"`).

If you need support for all characters, take a look at [the ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/), in particular [the part about case mappings](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/casemappings)

Comment: Is that solution for only Windows or same for Ubuntu? Because I tried them but codes not working.

Comment: @Yavuz: It should also work on Ubuntu, but it might depend on your locale setting. See the answer by Konrad Rudolph for how you can easily use a non-default locale.

Comment: I agree with what's said here minus the 'ß' conversion. The standard says that that should *not* convert to a "SS" nor to a 'ẞ': http://stackoverflow.com/a/37571371/2642059

Answer (score 3):

Like Bart has shown, C++ simply doesn’t like multi-byte encodings. Luckily, you can use Boost.Local to solve this without too much hassle. Here’s a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::locale loc = gen("en_US.UTF-8");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        std::cout << boost::locale::to_lower(line, loc) << '\n';
}
```

To compile, we need to link to the Boost.Locale library:

```
g++ -lboost_locale lower.cpp -o lower
```

And when we execute it, we get the following:

```
$ ./main <<< 'ICH HÄTTE GERNE EINEN SÜßEN HASEN'
ich hätte gerne einen süßen hasen
```