# How can I make switch-case statements case insensitive?

Tags: c

How can I make a switch-case statement to not be case sensitive?
Say I made something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char choice;
int main ()
{
char choice;
printf("Will you choose A,B, or C?\n>");
scanf(" %c", &choice);

switch(choice)
{
    case 'A': 
         printf("The First Letter of the Alphabet");
         break;
    case 'B':
         printf("The Second Letter of the Alphabet");
         break;
    case 'C':
         printf("The Third Letter of the Alphabet");
         break;
}
}
```

It would only respond to capital letters. How do I make it respond to lower case letters?

Comment: Lowercase/uppercase your choice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You simply need this :-

```
switch(choice)
{
case 'A': 
case 'a':
     printf("The First Letter of the Alphabet");
     break;
case 'B':
case 'b':
     printf("The Second Letter of the Alphabet");
     break;
case 'C':
case 'c':
     printf("The Third Letter of the Alphabet");
     break;
}
```

and so on to continue your series.

Actually,what it does is that it bypasses(skims) upto bottom until it finds the first break statement matching the case thereby executing all the cases encountered in between!!!

Comment: I was going to write that but my touchpad (Lenovo) is evil. Very very evilly broken. You won. :) +1

Comment: Thank You very much. My C learning book said nothing of this before moving onto the next choice method.

Comment: @Prof.Falken-Professor.,same here! But,I don't know how I won the race. Ha-ha-ha...

Comment: Lenovo B590?  @Jeremy, click the little accept check, the green, next to this answer.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvoting!

Comment: Well, if you get 10 upvotes or more, someone will likely downvote. Get used to it...

Comment: I dont like this a all. What if I have more than 1 latter switch, then you need to pass all options: AAA, AAa, Aaa, aaa, aaA,...

Comment: @GilEpshtain - It's fine if you don't like it. But, honestly, I didn't understand your point. Would you like to elaborate, please?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful - In case your switch key isn't a single letter the switch will be: `case SUNDAY: case SUNDAy: case SUNDaY: case SUNDay: ....` This is of course not maintainable

Answer (score 32):

`toupper` in  `<ctype.h>` converts a character to uppercase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char choice;
int main ()
{
printf("Will you choose A,B, or C?\n>");
scanf(" %c", &choice);

switch(toupper(choice))  // Changed line
{
    case 'A': 
         printf("The First Letter of the Alphabet");
         break;
    case 'B':
         printf("The Second Letter of the Alphabet");
         break;
    case 'C':
         printf("The Third Letter of the Alphabet");
         break;
}
```

Comment: I actually prefer this method. Seems more elegant and less error prone. Especially in this case where you are looking at case-insensitivising specifically.

Comment: @JoErNanO, in the general case yes, but it's also good to understand that the case construct can take several `case` after each other. I like both answers. If you user `toupper()`, you need to be aware of the limitations and quirks of runtime, if applicable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493496/c-c-utf-8-upper-lower-case-conversions  If you use several `case`, you need to be aware of the limitations of the compiler. It might only accept ASCII, for instance. Trade-offs. :)

Comment: @Prof. Falken I absolutely agree.

Answer (score 6):

Before the switch(), add:

```
choice = toupper(choice);
```

And if you haven't already got it, `#include <ctype.h>` to get the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You can give 2 cases one by one,

```
switch(choice)
{
case 'A':
case 'a':
     printf("The First Letter of the Alphabet");
     break;
case 'B':
case 'b':
     printf("The Second Letter of the Alphabet");
     break;
case 'C':
case 'c':
     printf("The Third Letter of the Alphabet");
     break;
}
```